# Using OneSignal Push Notifications with WebViewApp

Tags: javascript, onesignal

We have a HTML5 website which uses normal user login and password. We have encapsulated this in a WebView App purchased on CodeCanyon. The app has facility for OneSignal push notification which is configured and working fine.

We want to send user specific push notifications. In OneSignal we can see the device ID - but we don't get the user ID. In our website database we can see only the user ID.

We understand that some programming is required to link this.  We need help on achieving following:

a) When the user log in from the HTML5 website (and he is using mobile device) - it should update the OneSignal ID in the user table in the database.
b) The code for login is in JavaScript. There must definitely be some way to call OneSignal SDK (used by WebViewApp) in the JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have now.

Comment: Hi, @Rahul Jain! Are you still looking for an answer for this question?

Comment: I would like to understand if there is a solution available for this. I am having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the onesignal API documentation you have to send data tags in order to get that info 
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/add-user-data-tags